# In c++: what is the difference between initializing a variable in a function versus declaring it in the function header?

Tags: c++

Is the difference only in what you can do with them?

Also, how can you pass the result of a variable in a function to another function? Recently, I had to do this but the variable wasn't passing the code in the parent function to the other function.

```
  void add(int a, int b)
```

vs

```
   void add(int a)
        int b;
        a+b;
```

and for passing the result of a variable from a parent function to a function:

```
void add(int a, int b, double c)
    a+b=c;


void divide(double c, int d, double e)
    c / d = e;
```

Comment: Are you talking about local variables vs. global variables?

Comment: C wouldn't be from void add function, correct? Besides globals, is there anything else you can do? I'm reading up on scope and passing value/reference again but I was specifically confused about this. Talking about local variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a big difference between these two functions (I added some absent details)

```
void add(int a, int b)
{
   int c = a + b;
}

void add(int a)
{
   int b = 10;
   int c = a + b;
}
```

In the first case you can call the function passing two arguments. For example

```
add( 2, 5 );
```

and inside the function variable c will have a value depending of the two arguments (if a = 2, b = 5 then c = 7).

In the second case you can call the function passing only one argument

```
add( 2 );
```

So if to specify as argument 2 then you will get that c will be equal to 12.You can not change the value of b calling the function because you have no access to it.

Take into account that this code will not be compiled

```
void add(int a, int b, double c)
{
    a + b = c;
}
```

You may not assign the expression `a + b`

If you need to pass the result from one function to another then you can pass it through the function return object.For examploe change return type from `void` to `int` in the first function

```
int add(int a, int b)
{
   int c = a + b;
   return c;
}
```

In this case you can pass the result to "parent" function. For example

```
#include <iostream>

int add(int a, int b)
{
   int c = a + b;
   return c;
}

void add(int a, int b, double c)
{
    std::cout << a + b + c;
}


int main()
{
   int x = 10;
   int y = 20;
   int z = 30;

   add( x, y, add( x, z ) )'
}
```

The output will be equal to 70 ( x + y + (x + z ) ). In this example there are two overloaded functions with name add one of which has two parameters and the other has three parameters.

Also you can get a function result using parameters passed either by reference of using pointers.

For example

```
#include <iostream>


void add(int a, int b, double &c)
{
    c = a + b;
}


int main()
{
   int x = 10;
   int y = 20;
   int z;

   add( x, y, z ) );

   std::cout << "z = " << z << std::endl;
}
```

The result will be z = 30.

If to use poinetrs then the code will look as

```
#include <iostream>


void add(int a, int b, double *c)
{
    *c = a + b;
}


int main()
{
   int x = 10;
   int y = 20;
   int z;

   add( x, y, &z ) );

   std::cout << "z = " << z << std::endl;
}
```

The result will be the same that is 30.

Answer (score 1):

The difference is in the [scope](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_%28computer_science%29) of the variable. Variables declared in the function body will have [block scope](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_%28computer_science%29#Block_scope). Variables declared in the header will have [file scope](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_%28computer_science%29#File_scope).

Comment: Thanks, that helps. I guess I'm just confused about how passing variables between functions work. Would it be more correct to say parameters? I guess you can't pass variables unless it's through return.

Answer (score 0):

```
void add(int a, int b, double c)
    a+b=c;

void divide(double c, int d, double e)
    c / d = e;
```

This code is complete nonsense. Let my try to fix it for you:

```
int add(int a, int b)
{
    return a + b;
}

double divide(double c, int d)
{
    return c / d;
}
```

Not sure why one would restrict `d` to be an `int`. But hey, I don't even see the point in add and divide functions when one could simply use good old `+` and `/` to begin with :)

Comment: Thanks for fixing it. I didn't really do a correct example but the code formatting on this site is too awkward for me to correctly use (apparently).

Answer (score 0):

If you declare the function in a header it will be accessible in all the source files that include that header. This you can make either const, static, or extern. If you make it extern, do not forget that you will need also to define the variable in one of the source files:

```
// header.h
#pragma once

int a;             //these variables will be usable in all the source files that include this header
static const int b = 5;  //this is a const static variable, you cannot assign a new value to it.
extern int c;  // this is extern, must be defined in a soruce file

int fun(int); // and this is a function taking an int, returning another int
```

and the source file:

```
#include "header.h"

int fun(int g)
{
    return g + 1;
}

int c = 7;

int main()
{
   a = 5;    // assign a value to it
   fun(a);   // this is how you use it
}
```

If you initialize (assuming initialize means declare) a variable in the function, the variable will be accessible only from that function.

About the "result of a variable in a function to another function" possibly you want to create a function which takes a parameter. See the code above.